# How i can get active product details from magento database?

Tags: sql, magento

I need a list of ACTIVE products from the magento database with the following information.
If there are additional information that is fine, but the following information need to be there.

```
SKU:
PRODUCT NAME:
PRODUCT CATEGORY:
SHORT DESCRIPTION:
LONG DESCRIPTION:
WEIGHT:
```

What is the way to write a query for this. I just need to get the data. No php, just sql query.(Db structure is bit complex)

Answer (score 2):

try that, it works to get the product data: (status = 2 = product disabled, status = 1 = product enabled)

```
SELECT `e`.*, IF(_table_status.value_id > 0, _table_status.value, _table_status_default.value) AS `status
FROM `mage_catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
INNER JOIN `mage_catalog_product_entity_int` AS `_table_status_default`
ON (`_table_status_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`)
AND (`_table_status_default`.`attribute_id` = '80')
AND `_table_status_default`.`store_id` = 0
LEFT JOIN `mage_catalog_product_entity_int` AS `_table_status`
ON (`_table_status`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`)
AND (`_table_status`.`attribute_id` = (SELECT attribute_id FROM mage_eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'status' AND entity_type_id = 4))
AND (`_table_status`.`store_id` = '1')
WHERE (IF(_table_status.value_id > 0, _table_status.value, _table_status_default.value) = '2')
```

For the category you will need some extra work. I get this sql query by doing the following in PHP and the Magento collection:

```
/* @var $productCollection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection */
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$productCollection->addFieldToFilter('status', array('eq' => '2'))->load(true);
```

Comment: attribute_id is not fixed! You should replace the 80 by `SELECT * FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'status' AND entity_type_id = 4`